# SQL server TVP bulk insert more than 2000 params

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, mssql-jdbc, table-valued-parameters

```
CREATE TABLE EAddressDetails (EAddress varchar(100) NULL))

CREATE TYPE EAddressList AS TABLE (Email VARCHAR(100)))

CREATE PROCEDURE EAddresses_InsertBatch
@EAddressBatch [EAddressList] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO EAddressDetails (EAddress)
SELECT E.Email FROM @EAddressBatch E
SELECT EAddress
from EAddressDetails
END;
```

Executing the above stored procedure like the below

```
DECLARE @__sp_result int; DECLARE @EAddressBatch EAddressList;
INSERT INTO  @EAddressBatch(EAddress)
SELECT EAddress FROM (VALUES (?),(?)...2000 rows,(?)) s(EAddress);
EXECUTE @__sp_result = EAddresses_InsertBatch @EAddressBatch=@EAddressBatch;
SELECT @__sp_result AS __sp_result;
```

`The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.: S0001`

Is there any efficient way to insert more than 2100 parameters.

Comment: Seems like you would be better off with a BULK operation here.

Comment: hmm.. But the setup is to use TVP. :(

Comment: Not sure if my query is efficient here

Comment: Do you have an insert trigger on EAddressDetails? Is it trying to use the `IN` operator over the `inserted` virtual table?

Comment: Pass the email addresses as a table-valued parameter from the app code, not individual scalar parameters. This will be much more efficient, avoid the insert into the table variable, and avoid the 2100 parameter limit. The T-SQL code would be `DECLARE @__sp_result int;EXECUTE @__sp_result = EAddresses_InsertBatch @EAddressBatch=?;SELECT @__sp_result AS __sp_result;`

Comment: @DanGuzman How do I add data to TVP?

Comment: @user3636388, the [jdbc documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15) has some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the email addresses as a table-valued parameter from the app code rather than individual scalar parameters. This will be much more efficient, avoid the insert into the table variable, and avoid the 2100 parameter limit.

The modified T-SQL code with this method would be:

```
DECLARE @__sp_result int;
EXECUTE @__sp_result = EAddresses_InsertBatch @EAddressBatch=?;
SELECT @__sp_result AS __sp_result;
```

See the [Microsoft SQL Server jdbc driver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15) for java example code.

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, another way to pass the list is with a JSON array parameter. Example below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EAddresses_InsertBatch
    @EAddressBatch varchar(MAX)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO EAddressDetails (EAddress)
    SELECT E.Email
    FROM OPENJSON(@EAddressBatch)
    WITH (
        EMail varchar(100) '$'
    ) AS E;
GO

EXEC EAddresses_InsertBatch '["test1@example.com","test2@example.com","test3@example.com"]';
GO
```

Comment: Still figuring this out. Not sure how the values will be passed.

Comment: @user3636388, I added a JSON example to my answer if you find that method easier. That avoids the need for a table type.

Comment: Is there a way to send without changing the procedure in the question. I have no control over the procedure.

Comment: The above works like a charm though. But the requirement is to use TVP and not change anything in the procedure